# How can i use babel interpreter on pm2 cluster mode

Tags: babeljs, pm2, cluster-mode

I'm having an error about my ES codes because the babel-node doesn't work when I run the app in pm2 cluster mode, but in fork mode, it run successfully, it says [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1167#issuecomment-97310680) that `--interpreter` can't work in cluster mode `(-i)` due to its operating principle..., so what should I do to run my application that use the latest version of ECMAScript?

My error is

```
/home/dylan/Projects/project-name/src/index.js:1
import express from 'express'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
   ...
```

My Script

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production & pm2 start src --interpreter babel-node -i 2",
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need babel to use import syntax in nodejs. You could enable it in package.json or by using mjs extension. Here is more info about it:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Comment: I am using node13.10 version. I tried both using .mjs file and with type:module  both are not working for me. any suggestions?